# Understanding the Absence of AsNotTracking() in the ABP Framework - Alternative Approaches for Improving Performance

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, abp

I'm currently working with the ABP framework and noticed the absence of the AsNotTracking() method, commonly found in other ORMs (Object-Relational Mapping). AsNotTracking() is typically used to enhance performance by indicating that queries should not track changes made to entities.

Since I couldn't locate this specific method in the ABP framework, I would appreciate guidance on alternative approaches or best practices for achieving similar performance improvements. Specifically, I'm interested in understanding how to effectively handle entity tracking and performance optimization in the ABP framework.

Comment: `AsNoTracking()` is located in `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` namespace. Add to your project reference to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` library.